# Python adding elements of a list together to get a new list

Tags: python

lets say I have a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to add the elements of the list to create a new list like so:

```
newlist = [(1+2),(3+4),(5+6),(7+8)]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Iterate through the indexes of the loop in steps of 2. Then you can add `list1[i] + list1[i+1]` and return a list of the results.

Comment: what would you expect if you had an odd number of elements? i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 5):

Using an iterator

```
s = iter(list1)
list(map(sum, zip(s,s)))
```

---

```
[3, 7, 11, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using zip and list slicing:

```
 [x+y for x, y in zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

With an array like this

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The easiest to understand code would be something like this

```
new_list = []
for index in range(0,len(list),2):
   sum = list[index] + list[index+1]
   new_list.append(sum)
```

Of course, that is a bit length. We can do the same thing using list comprehension.

```
list = [list[index] + list[index+1] for index in range(0,len(list),2)]
```

or another option:

```
list = [x+y for x, y in zip(list[::2], list[1::2])]
```